# Please help us pick "low hanging fruit" for our upcoming releases

Tags: discussion

SDL Tridion (Sites) PM will be focusing more on Community Ideas for upcoming releases (SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 and beyond; 9.0 scope is already full at the moment).

At the least, we're looking for "low hanging fruit": popular ideas which are not very costly to implement.
For that purpose, we will be looking for ideas with many votes (and in particular: many distinct voting parties) on the [SDL Community site](https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas)

To make this a fair game, we want to ensure we have a good representation of customers and partners submitting and voting for ideas.

So, a little call-to-action for everyone:

- Did you already submit all your ideas (in particular the ones which don't seem very hard to implement)?
- Did you already vote for other ideas you support?
- If not, can you please do so ASAP? By submitting and voting you will be able to influence what is in the 9.1 release, but it will take some time for Ideas to mature.

You may have submitted ideas with SDL earlier through other channels, for example the former SDL Tridion Ideas site (which was taken down in April 2016) or SDL Support.
We have already recreated some of these enhancement requests on SDL Tridion Sites Ideas, but we kindly ask you to see if they’re already on SDL Ideas and to resubmit them if they’re still relevant for you.